# Extract alt text of WordPress images

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to edit this code to display alt text of every images in front-end which i upload in WordPress. Currently it shows a default text for all images. What's the extracting php code for getting alt text from this code.

```
<img src="'.esc_url($image_url[0]).'" alt="image"/>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get any image alt value then you can get by its URL. Your solution will be,

```
$image_id = attachment_url_to_postid($image_url[0] );
echo get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

**Updated**

So your code would be,

```
<img src="'.esc_url($image_url[0]).'" alt="'.esc_attr(get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)).'"/>
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/263wche check this and tell what to be replaced inside alt"" to call alt attributes of images. I'm confused with above answer

Comment: Actually here according to code shown in image whatever inside alt"text" will be shown to all images instead of alt value which we given to images in WordPress image editor. I want to show each images image editor provided alt values to front end instead of a default value.

Comment: I want to show the correct alt value given in wordpress image editor to front end instead of a default value.

Comment: I updated my answer... you can get all alt text by your image URL.

Comment: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 32 of file wp-content/plugins/testhouse-addon/include-elements/content-with-image-element.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO). I'm getting this error please check.

Comment: ), $atts));
  
  $pg_content = '';
  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($content_image,'full');
  $pg_content .= '

Comment: please check now I updated the code..

Comment: The code has been successfully added but the alt field is still empty when i inspected the image from browser. (alt="").

Comment: try to echo this function (get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)) . And check the function is return any data or not . I don't know how you implement  this https://prnt.sc/263wche code, so..

Comment: function th_content_with_image_element_func($atts, $content = null)
    {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    
   'paragraph_title_color' => '',
   'paragraph_title' => '',
   'content_image' => '',
   'image_class' => '',
   
        ), $atts));
  
  $pg_content = '';
  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($content_image,'full');
  $pg_content .= '

Comment: output https://i.postimg.cc/NjK2T9Kf/screenshot-47.png